# Command Line Arguments wxCmdLineArgsArray in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, c, command-line-arguments, wxwidgets

After Converting a C++ Project to unicode, command line arguments of C files which were declared as char is now declared to wxCmdLineArgsArray. Previous declarations of char is causing error as cannot convert wxCmdCharlineArgsArray to char**.  How to resolve the errors? How to convert wxCmdlineArgsArray to char**?

Comment: Ask your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Include some code. Include the _exact_ error messages (copy & paste them).

Answer (score 1):

[`wxCmdLineArgsArray`](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/cmdargs.h) has conversions for `operator char**() const` and `operator wchar_t**() const`.

You need to use `const char**` rather then `char**`.  However if teh args are Unicode you will need `const wchar_t**`.

However why would you not simply use `wxString operator[](size_t n) const` and either use the `wxString` directly or convert that?  `wxString` has numerous conversion methods for various string types.

Comment: @Babitha : Does not need to be _the_ code, or even all the code.  Just an example that exhibits the same problem, or even just the line that reports the error message.

Comment: @Babitha : even with an explicit cast?

Comment: @Babitha : Use type wchar_t** rather than wchar_t*[]

Comment: Yes even with an explicit cast. I have edited the question. Could you please go through it and help me out?

Comment: @Babitha : Different error, post a new question.  And for that you will need to provide at least the line of code causing the error and information on data types.  It looks like a simple type mismatch however.  Without visibility of the code I cannot know what you have changed.  It is hard to advise.

Comment: @Babitha : meh.  You cannot be helped if you are not prepared to help yourself.  You need to present some code and the error message in the question, not in comments.